# Iterate over the next two children of an XML?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I want to iterate through a XML which alternates between two types of child nodes (`activity` and `leg`):

```xml
<person id="100010701">
    <plan score="80.11179641489682" selected="yes">
        <activity type="home_46200.0" link="10723" x="4632239.860061693" y="5826584.427915721" end_time="03:59:47" >

        </activity>
        <leg mode="transit_walk" dep_time="03:59:47">
            <route type="generic" start_link="10723" end_link="10723" trav_time="00:15:20" distance="747.1733687259284"></route>
        </leg>
        <activity type="leisure_2400.0" link="10723" x="4631524.841132437" y="5826801.259587159" max_dur="00:00:00" >
        </activity>
        <leg mode="non_network_walk" dep_time="04:15:07">
            <route type="generic" start_link="10723" end_link="10723" trav_time="00:23:01" distance="2763.424921008634"></route>
        </leg>
        <activity type="car interaction" link="10723" x="4633422.149064934" y="5827759.837646425" max_dur="00:00:00" >
        </activity>
        ...
    </plan>
</person>
```

For my computation I need the `x` and `y` attributes from the activity, as well as the `trav_time` and `distance` from the leg.
My naive approach was to iterate through each child element of plan and check what kind of node it is. Depending on the type, I either save some variables or run some code with the saved variables.

```
for elem in plan:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    if (elem.tag == "activity"):
       x = elem.get("x")
       y = elem.get("y")
    if (elem.tag == "leg"):
       trav_time = elem.find("route").get("trav_time")
       distance = elem.find("route").get("distance")
       doSomething(trav_time, distance, x, y)
```

But this seems quite clumsy and not concise. What I really want is to loop over the next `activity` and following `leg` like this (I know this will not work for good reason):

```
for activity, leg in plan:
   x = activity.get("x")
   y = activity.get("y")
   trav_time = leg.find("route").get("trav_time")
   distance = leg.find("route").get("distance")
   doSomething(trav_time, distance, x, y)
```

So is there a concise way to iterate over the next 2 consecutive children of the parent node?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<person id="100010701">
    <plan score="80.11179641489682" selected="yes">
        <activity type="home_46200.0" link="10723" x="4632239.860061693" y="5826584.427915721" end_time="03:59:47" >

        </activity>
        <leg mode="transit_walk" dep_time="03:59:47">
            <route type="generic" start_link="10723" end_link="10723" trav_time="00:15:20" distance="747.1733687259284"></route>
        </leg>
        <activity type="leisure_2400.0" link="10723" x="4631524.841132437" y="5826801.259587159" max_dur="00:00:00" >
        </activity>
        <leg mode="non_network_walk" dep_time="04:15:07">
            <route type="generic" start_link="10723" end_link="10723" trav_time="00:23:01" distance="2763.424921008634"></route>
        </leg>
        <activity type="car interaction" link="10723" x="4633422.149064934" y="5827759.837646425" max_dur="00:00:00" >
        </activity>
    </plan>
</person>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
plans = root.findall(".//plan")
for plan in plans:
  activities =  plan.findall('./activity')
  legs =  plan.findall('./leg')
pairs = zip(activities,legs)
data = []
for activity,leg in pairs:
  entry = {}
  entry['x'] = activity.attrib['x']
  entry['y'] = activity.attrib['y']
  route = leg.find('route')
  entry['trav_time'] = route.attrib['trav_time']
  data.append(entry)

print(data)
```